# Load panel content after page load

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have dashboard with panels:

```
<p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardOptionsMB.model}">            
   <c:forEach var="item" items="#{dashboardOptionsMB.emsWidgets}">
    <ui:include src="/pages/dashboard/panel.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="widget" value="#{item.webDashboardDbBean}" />
        <ui:param name="emsValue" value="#{item.emsValue}" />
    </ui:include>
   </c:forEach>
</p:dashboard>
```

I load a list `dashboardOptionsMB.emsWidgets` with content before rendering page, and this works fine with panel component:

panel.xhtml:

```
    <p:panel id="#{widget.widgetid}" header="#{widget.widgetheader}" closable="true" >
       <h:outputText value="#{emsValue.value}" />
       ...
    </panel>
```

So, before each rendering I initialize the list with all elements and content with this method:

DashboardOptionsMB:

```
    private void initWidgets(WebDashboardsDbBean dashboard) {
      //dashboard is JPA entity from database
      emsWidgets = dashboard.getWidgets();
      ...
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to load each panel content dynamically after page load. For example each panel should call:

```
initWidget(String widgetId)
```

after page load, and when this method is completed to update its content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`p:remoteCommand`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) to create some Ajaxified Javascript which will be executed when body is loaded:

```
<h:body onload="loadWidgets()">
    <!-- content --> 
    <p:remoteCommand name="loadWidgets" 
        update="#{widget.widgetid}" 
        actionListener="#{dashboardOptionsMB.initWidgets}"/>  
</h:body>
```

Alternatively, you might use the `autoRun="true"` argument to have it executed when document is ready:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="loadWidgets" 
    update="#{widget.widgetid}" 
    actionListener="#{dashboardOptionsMB.initWidgets}"
    autoRun="true"/>
```

**See also:**

- [JSF lazy loading component value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389857/jsf-lazy-loading-component-value)
- [Make your Primefaces app load faster with lazy loading](https://blogs.realdolmen.com/experts/2014/08/14/make-your-primefaces-app-load-faster-with-lazy-loading/)