# p:remoteCommand async autoRun runs calls 6 by 6

Tags: jquery, ajax, primefaces, remotecommand

We have a simple JSF + **PrimeFaces 6.1** project which is for now a POC to solve a problem that we have in our actual project, which is basically the need to load JSF/PF components concurrently.
I was able to implement it adapting the solution from this answer here from Stackoverflow: [JSF lazy loading component value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389857/jsf-lazy-loading-component-value)

But the "problem"/question now is: why are the **async** **remoteCommand** calls invoked in **groups of 6** and the following 6 are queued and so on?
Is it a browser thing, jQuery configuration/limitation or an actual p:remoteCommand limitation? I wasn't able to find a property to set unlimited or 10 or 12 for instance.

**Obs: I have tried both with and without the autoRun and invoked them by their names, but the result was the same. 6 by 6.**

Chrome Network Timeline below:
[image]

Code fragment below:

```
<p:remoteCommand async="true" id="rcLoadWidget" 
   actionListener="#{dashboardController.loadWidget}"
   process="panelGroup" autoRun="true"
   partialSubmit="true" update="panelWidget @form:btSave" />
```

Could you please advise? :)

Comment: PrimeFaces 6.1 does not include jquery 3.2.1 so try removing that first (assuming you added that manually). And regarding "Is it a browser thing," google is your friend... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser. And you can already see the browser knows about them (the grey line) so it is not a queue in jquery, nor Primefaces. Easy deduction

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the good observation! I was in fact including jQuery because I'd started with a plain html and forgot to remove it.
But most importantly, the "max parallel http connections in a browser" really answered my question.
I will look for different approaches to load more content (components) concurrently, if you know of any please let me know. Thanks!